# how to build subpage with the same header.php?

Tags: php, html

**my goal:**  is when i click the sign up link it will move me to the signup.php and it will show the page!

i am trying to build asub page with the same login form header with php, 
 but when i start using the

```
 <?php
include_once 'header.php';

?>
```

it dosent work and it dosent move me to the subapge!

here is the code :

**index.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'header.php';

?>

<section class="main-container">

<div class="main-warrper">

<h2> signup </h2> 
</div>

 </section>

<?php
include_once 'footer.php';

?>
```

**header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<title> login form </title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style22.css">

</head> 

<body> 

<header>

<nav>

<div class= "main-warrper">  
<ul> 

    <li><a href="index.php">home </a></li>
</ul>
<div class="nav-login"> 
<form> 
<input type = "text" name="uid" placeholder="email"> 
<input type = "password" name="pwd" placeholder="password"> 
 <button type="submit" name="submit"> login </button>   
    </form>
<a href="signup.php">sign up </a> 
</div>

</div>
 </nav> 

</header>
```

**signup.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'header.php';

?>

<section class="main-container">

<div class="main-warrper">

<h2> signup </h2> 
</div>

 </section>

<?php
include_once 'footer.php';

?>
```

Comment: What means that it doesn't work. Does it show some error? Or do you get page doesn't exist?

Comment: i get the php code!

Comment: i want to get the pagE

Comment: Is your server (for example XAMPP) running?

Comment: *"i get the php code!"* - What do you mean by that, you see "code"?

Comment: your code for `index.php` and `signup.php` is identical. how do you know you are on each page?

Comment: dont know ' i dont runn it anywere! jest in the brawoser

Comment: when you click on the sign up .php the <h2> tage cange to sign up from home

Comment: Ok @david33, you have to run server to be able to write PHP code and run it on local machine. I would suggest you to install xampp, because it is easy to install. You can use some tutorial for example [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mllgHw5YGhM)

Comment: hoo great thaks it works! like you said

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to move screen to position of login, signup in one page.

```html
<header page>
<index page>
<a href=#signup>sign up</a>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<signup page here>
<div id=signup style="color:red;"><input type=text>sing in
</div>
```

>